# Manage different requirements for different clients in software product

Tags: product

I am working on a product that is in production for one client. Now we are trying to sell this product to other clients and the challenge I would see is if other clients want to add different rules and/or additional information which will not be relevant to the previous client. How should I manage to incorporate such changes in the system.

For your reference, I have developed this product in asp.net MVC + angularjs and SQL server at the backend.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue with our clients aswell but we are using Java with spring boot.
we overcame this issue with @ConditionalOnBean. For example, we have different handlers in service. Models and Services are common but service implementations are different. We basically use ConditionalOnBean(Client1Indicator.class). In our application.properties we declare which client which indicator to use. So when our client use it basically use its own service implementation. I don't know if there is one in asp.net or in angularJs but maybe this will help you.